# Copy exact error message from XCODE

Tags: xcode

I wonder How could I copy the exact error message on XCODE.

[image: inline]

[image: inline]

[image: inline]

Tried to click Copy from the menu on the debug window, it will give you useless debug error message. You could not use it to google the answer.

How could I copy the exact error message.

Or Xcode is absent from this basic feature as a powerful IDE?

```
file:///Users/xxx/Dropbox/xxcourses%20%E7%BE%8E%E5%9C%8B%E8%AA%B2%E7%A8%8B/iOS/hw2/hw2/MainVC.swift:68:50:%20Invalid%20conversion%20from%20throwing%20function%20of%20type%20'(_,%20_,%20_)%20throws%20-%3E%20()'%20to%20non-throwing%20function%20type%20'(NSData%3F,%20NSURLResponse%3F,%20NSError%3F)%20-%3E%20Void'
```